# Sql request selection

Tags: sql

I' trying to get all the Missions getting the same contract.

Ex:

If this is the data of Mission

```
Mission Id   Contract Id
-------------------------
    1            1
    2            2
    3            2
    4            3
```

How can I get `2-2` and `3-2` ?

I've tried many weird stuff but nothing works :(

Thanks for your help

Comment: Well...i know what's a where clause ! But I don't know what to use here to filter as i want.

Comment: Find those contracts with more than one mission and put it into a subquery: `select * from tab where contractid in (select contractid from tab group by contractid having count(*) >1)`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query below uses a Join which should be faster than a subquery.

```
    Select t1.ContractId, t2.MissionId 
    From tab t1
    Join tab t2 ON t1.ContractId = t2.ContractId
    Group By t1.ContractId, t2.MissionId 
    Having Count(*) > 1
```

Comment: This might create a huge intermediate result before aggregation due to the many-to-many join. If you think that a subquery is slower better move it into a Derived Table before joining: `select t1.* from tab as t1 join (select contractid from tab group by contractid having count(*) >1) as t2 on t1.contractid  = t2.contractid`

Comment: You are right, it's the best answer.It reduces the number of reads substantially.